# VS2015 Project wont run in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Not a duplicate of: [VS2015 Project no longer runs in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992705/vs2015-project-no-longer-runs-in-debug-mode#)

My issue is the same though, except I have already tried the solutions from that question. Things I have tried/checked:

- Optimize Code is not checked
- Config Manager is set to Build and Debug
- Define DEBUG and TRACE constant is checked
- Cleaning / Rebuilding
- Changing the above settings, saving, changing back.
- Deleting the DLL it complains about being in debug mode and recompiling.

I have no idea what else to check. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Attach/run the project regardless of the warning, then check the "Modules" window (Debug -> Windows -> Modules) and find out where the DLL/EXE is being loaded from.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson Didn't think of that!!! Was loading from temp asp.net. Stupid. If you make that comment an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 1):

Attach/run the project regardless of the warning. Open the "Modules" window (Debug -> Windows -> Modules) and find out where the DLL/EXE is being loaded from.

Answer (score 0):

One.  Try removing every "project reference" and re-adding them.

Two..when really up against it, create a new solution..new projects (same names are ok)....and move the non sln/csproj files over (.cs files mainly) and readd them to your NEW csproj/sln files.  Aka, "recreate it"...  Twice I've had to do this for no known reason.