# A forgotten warning's consequences in [VS] - errors not showing up

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, class-library

I skipped a very important warning and later I noticed my errors weren't showing up. Here's what happened  . . .

A Warning popped up when I hit the play button to test my class library from a other windows form application  in the solution explorer. It had 4 options "stop debugging", "start without my code", "continue debugging" and "do not show this error again", and I clearly remember it saying something about "This is a release version of my class library, switch to debug etc... can't remember, and something about breakpoints won't show up". I didn't know what this was at first and it kept popping every time when I hit the play button, so I chose the last option "do not show this error again", and later I realized my problem when I was coding.

This happened when I builded a release version of my class library and by adding the dll to a other whole new project, after this I went back to my class library's project to add a new windows form application to test something else in my class library and this warning popped up.

I want to know about this warning and how I can I trigger it again. And I hope your familiar with this warning, because I can't clearly remember it.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [TOUR].  No one here can tell you what the warning is that you ignored

Comment: My bad I only had my attention for a few of them on "Ask A Question" page, never thought there would be more to it. And for my problem I did some searching and I can't find the solution and I just wanted to know if anyone reading this is familiar with the warning so I can search it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... there's a couple versions of what you are describing and they happen for similar reasons.

1. You are debugging a process and visual studio notices that the source at the breakpoint being hit differs from when the pdb file was built.
2. You've attached to a process that was built in release mode without full pdb symbols (or possibly any pdb symbols).
3. You attempt to start debugging but compilation fails.

You should look in the settings by going to `Tools` > `Options` > `Debugging` > `General`. If I were to guess, the box saying "Warn if no user code on launch" is unchecked under "Just my code" or the "Warn about stale code" option under "Enable edit and continue" is unchecked.

Comment: Thanks, this showed my error and I did some searching and turns out it is a old bug. [This Is My Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028341/vs-2015-update-1-claiming-i-am-debugging-a-release-build), I followed @Bps comment. Deleted my dll in the bin folder and rebuilded and added it again, and now its solved