# Visual Studio 2022 not hitting break point

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I have very simple console app to read csv file. The problem is that when I set break point it does not hit.
I tried re-installing my visual studio, clearing VS temporary and cache files, as well as what suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582022/visual-studio-breakpoints-not-being-hit) without success. My configuration is Debug mode.
[image]

My code is here:

```
namespace ExtractCSV
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var trades = "../../../../trades.csv";
            Console.WriteLine(trades);

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(trades))
            {
                string currentLine;
                var headers = sr.ReadLine();
                char delimeter = ',';
                var headersSplit = headers.Split(delimeter);
                var openTimeIndex = Array.IndexOf(headersSplit, "opentime");
                var closeTimeIndex = Array.IndexOf(headersSplit, "closetime");
                var timesrcIndex = Array.IndexOf(headersSplit, "timesrc");

                // currentLine will be null when the StreamReader reaches the end of file
                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    var split = currentLine.Split(delimeter);
                    //var split = Regex.Split(currentLine, ",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
                    if (split.Length > 17)
                    {
                        var openTime = split[openTimeIndex].Replace("T", " ");
                        var closeTime = split[closeTimeIndex].Replace("T", " ");
                        var timesrcTime = split[timesrcIndex].Replace("T", " ");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hitting F10 does not get you into debugging of the first line? Does you programm then run to the end so you get to see console output at least?

Comment: Haves you checked the possibilities in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31992834/43846

Comment: Yes, even if I put the break point at the first line, it does not hit. Program goes to the end.

ExtractCSV\ExtractCSV\bin\x64\Debug\net8.0\ExtractCSV.exe (process 30416) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .

Comment: Then we need to look at the project setup. In your screenshot we see a x64 configuration in use. AFAIK the standard vs2022 templates initialy only has a "Any CPU" configuration. So how does the x64 configuration look you created? The typically setup errors for configurations should be described in @stuartd link.

Comment: I tried different configurations (including x86). Reverted configuration changes to AnyCPU;x64. Still not hitting brakepoint.

```<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
 <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup> ```

Comment: You have some issues in the configuration. Check whether you are actually generating the `.pdb` files (`Project Properties -> Build -> Debug Symbols`). You should hit breakpoints also in Release mode, if you start with the debugger attached

Comment: Current selction for Debug symbols is "PBD file, portable accross platforms". I can confirm that PBD file is generated.

Comment: Then for a check create a new console app via VS, copy the code over and don't touch configuration. Does that work?

Comment: Nope. It didn't work.

Comment: Then i'm almost out of easy ideas. You may try adding a Console.ReadLine and when the code hangs there waiting for input break the debugger. Then check debug output, loaded modules whatever visual studio has as debugging tools not coming to my mind currently and if can you see messages etc. that are hinting what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

In VS, go to Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> General, and then cancel the checks in front of `Enable "Only My Code"` and `Require source files to exactly match the original version`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: @PenkoYordanov If you break on other code or recreate a project for debugging, Visual Studio still can't catch the breakpoint?